# How to 'rm' or 'mv' a range of files such as file01.txt, file02.txt...file85.txt

Tags: command-line, bash

Suppose I have a bunch of files named this way:

```
file01.txt file02.txt file03.txt ... file20.txt
```

and I want to execute a command on a range of these files.

I know if want to 'rm' from 'file05.txt' to 'file09.txt' I can do:

```
rm file0[5-9].txt
```

but how can I 'rm' a range from file08.txt to file13.txt? I tried this code

```
rm file[08-13].txt
```

and it doesn't work.
I could run this command:

```
rm file0[89].txt file1[0-3].txt
```

but I'd like to know if I can do this with only one more refined argument to 'rm' if it is possible.

Comment: An almost identical question was answered here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049411/in-bash-how-can-i-remove-a-numeric-range-of-directories/25049445#25049445

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to use brace expansion of `bash`:

```
rm file{08..13}.txt
```

This will remove files `file08` to `file13`, will show an error message if any file is missing.

Set the range to meet your need.

---

The problem with the globbing operator `[]` is that it treats each character/digit inside it as a single token and so only supports range declaration using single digits.

If you insist on using `[]`, you can use this rather ugly pattern to match `file08` to `file13`:

```
rm file0[8-9].txt file1[0-3].txt
```

Comment: brace expansion is also useful with commas, like for `mv foo.{txt,md}` or `cp foo.txt{,.bak}`

Answer (score 2):

Some shells, such as Ubuntu's default `/bin/sh` ( which is `dash` ) or  `mksh` don't have brace expansion, or in case of `ksh` - brace expansion can't use padded zeroes :

```
$ ksh -c 'echo {05..13}'
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

In such cases, we can make use of `printf` to format the number portion of the filename, and use a while loop to implement c-like for loop behavior (note to replace `echo` with `rm` or whatever you want):

```
$ i=5; while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do num=$(printf "%.2d" "$i" ); echo "file$num.txt";i=$(($i+1)); done
file05.txt
file06.txt
file07.txt
file08.txt
file09.txt
file10.txt
```

And this is fairly portable - works with `dash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, also `bash`. In the case of `ksh` and `bash` we can also use `c-style for loop syntax (but not in case of`mksh`or`dash`):

```
$ ksh -c 'for((i=5;i<11;i++)); do num=$(printf "%.2d" "$i" ); echo "file$num.txt";done'             
file05.txt
file06.txt
file07.txt
file08.txt
file09.txt
file10.txt
```

Note that in `bash`'s case, `printf` supports printing to variable, and thus we could do `printf -v num "%.2d" "$i"` instead of using command substitution.